# While running test case ClientHttpResponse is throwing 401 error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a problem with my unit test. In my unit test I am getting 401 *Unauthorised* as response status and I don't know how to solve this problem. This is not a Spring project.

My Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LTest {

    @Test
    public void test_retrieve() throws Exceptions{
        CloseableHttpClient mockHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse mockHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
        HttpEntity mockEntity = mock(HttpEntity.class);
        StatusLine mockStatusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

        when(mockHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(new URIBuilder(anyString()).build()))).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);
        when(mockHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(mockEntity);
        when(mockHttpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusLine);
        when(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        Map<String, Employee> map = sample.retrieve();
        assertNotNull(map);
        assertEquals(1,map.size());
    }
```

source code for the above test case

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientUtils.setupClient(HttpClientBuilder.create()).build();
        String url = "http://someexample.com";
        UriBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url)
                .setParameter("limit",5)
                .setParameter("centre",centre);

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(builder.build()));
        if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            try{
                String entity = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entity,ObjectNode.class);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

While running the test case it's showing assertion error because it's going through catch block due below line is throwing 401 instead of 200

```
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(builder.build()));
```

Can anyone please help me with the above error I am getting?

Comment: You are not mocking the http client `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientUtils.setupClient(HttpClientBuilder.create()).build();`. One option is to extract this line to a seperate `getHttpClient()` method. Mock or override the method and pass the `mockHttpClient`

Comment: yes I figured out that already this line is creating the problem but how to mock or override I am not getting. I am new to writing test case

Comment: something like this I need to do? `@Override
        protected HttpClient getHttpClient() {
            return mockHttpClient;
        }`

Comment: I added an answer, see if it suits your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test, `HTTPClient` is not mocked and that is the reason for the failure.

To mock the `HTTPClient` we can follow the below strategy

1. Extract `getHttpClient()` in the ClassToBeTested as

```
public class HttpClientToBeTested {

    public Map retrieve() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
        String url = "http://someexample.com";

        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url)
                .setParameter("limit","5")
                .setParameter("centre","centre");

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(builder.build()));
        if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            try{
                String entity = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                //ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entity,ObjectNode.class);
                Map node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entity, Map.class); // Assume ObjectNode is a custom class, so for demo using Map.
                return node;
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // New extracted method that will be mocked in the test case
    protected CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

2. Next in the test class, we can inject the mock by subclassing the ClassToBeTested in an anonymous class as follows.

```
@Test
public void test_retrieve() throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient mockHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    CloseableHttpResponse mockHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
    //HttpEntity mockEntity = mock(HttpEntity.class); Not required since we will pass actual entity
    StatusLine mockStatusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

    when(mockHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(new URIBuilder(anyString()).build()))).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);
    when(mockHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(new StringEntity("{\"key\":\"value\"}")); // Important: Pass your actual response as string here.
    when(mockHttpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusLine);
    when(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

    // Code to mock the http client
    HttpClientToBeTested sample = new HttpClientToBeTested() {
        @Override
        protected CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
            return mockHttpClient;
        }
    };

    Map map = sample.retrieve();
    assertNotNull(map);
    assertEquals(1,map.size());
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** After mocking the httpClient, `httpClient.execute()` should return `SC_OK`. However, post that deserializing the response will fail since the mock `HttpEntity` will return null. To avoid it, we will rather send a `StringEntity`. Updated the actual and test class with the details.

Comment: @Override is throwing error. method does not override method from it's superclass.

Comment: it didn't help me. still same issue persists.

Comment: Can you please scroll up, the code is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: When I tried mocking httpClient the test case threw me NullPointerException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225901/discussion-between-jdeveloper-and-prasanna).

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have declared the CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse on the top and then trying to access the object inside the else block. That was creating the issue.

Comment: @JDeveloper. good to know, it worked. I have responded to your last query in chat room. Kindly check it.